# Why does this interval stop ticking in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I was playing with this example timer and then wanted to see if I could capture/pass data into the timer so I started with a simple message. If I remove the message to timer it ticks accordingly. I started logging other lifecycle methods but I am curious if this is JS thing which I don't think it is versus something in react life cycle. I forked a JS bin [here with ex](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lhnq7a9/)

'code'

```
var Timer = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
 return {secondsElapsed: 0};
},
tick: function(msg) {
 console.log('msg is',msg);
 this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});
},
componentDidMount: function() {
 this.interval = setInterval(this.tick('hi'), 1000);
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
 clearInterval(this.interval);
},
render: function() {
 return (
   <div>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</div>
 );
}
});

React.render(<Timer />, document.getElementById("content"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to change this bit in your code:

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick('hi'), 1000);
```

Alternatively, you can also send in `this` to the callback:

```
this.interval = setInterval(function(t) {t.tick('hi')}, 1000, this);
```

See the updated fiddle, [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lhnq7a9/1/).

---

[**`setInterval()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) takes (at least) two parameters, the first one is the callback and needs to be a function. You had provided the code directly; that code must be inside a function.

> ```
> var intervalID = scope.setInterval(func, delay);
> ```
>
> **func**
>
> A function to be executed every delay milliseconds. The function is not passed any parameters, and no return value is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change code to:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
   this.interval = setInterval(()=>this.tick('hi'), 1000);
}
```

Comment: can you expand a bit why is the component unmounting

Comment: @Barry we component unmounting beacuse no used and when component unmounting page is easy render other component in big project